# Import module dynamically

Tags: python, python-import

I have a program that supports different communication protocols. The idea is, that the user chooses the protocol during startup and then the module supporting the respective protocol is imported.

The function below populates the `protocol` module with all functions and variables from the user-chosen protocol.

`protocol.py`:

```
def provide_protocol( name ):
    for key, val in vars( __import__( name ) ).items():
        if key.startswith( "__" ) and key.endswith( "__" ):
            continue
        vars()[key] = val

    importlib.invalidate_caches()
```

`name` is provided by the user at program startup.

The issue is, that `protocol.py` is imported before this function is run and the program is not able to access the newly populated functions in this previously empty module.

Using `invalidate_caches()` from the `importlib` module does not change this.

---

I also tried, to remove `protocol.py` and create the whole module dynamically using `importlib`, but this also did not succeed:

`__init__.py`:

```
protocol = None
def provide_protocol( name ):
    protocol = importlib.import_module( name )
    importlib.invalidate_caches()
```

The problem seems to be identical, because if I import `protocol`, it seems to be `None`.

Comment: Both of your functions do nothing useful with the module you import, and it is simply discarded. `vars()[key] = val` in a function just assigns to a `dict` object returned by `locals()` which has no effect on anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your functions don't don't return anything useful (they both return `None`). Your first function tries to modify `vars`, but that won't do anything useful. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):

> Without an argument, `vars()` acts like `locals()`. Note, the locals
> dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals
> dictionary are ignored.

Note, if you had done that in a global scope, `locals() is globals()`, so those modifications would take effect, but since you are doing it in a function, nothing happens.

In your second function, you assign to a local variable `protocol` then don't do anything with it. The global variable `protocol` will remain `None`. You should just `return protocol` then use it like:

```
def provide_protocol( name ):
    protocol = importlib.import_module( name )
    importlib.invalidate_caches()
    return protocol


protocol = provide_protocol(name)
```

Note, in both cases, the module would still be in the cache, so:

```
import sys
protocol = sys.modules[name]
```

Would have retrieved it. But you should just explicitly return and assign it to whatever name you want.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to solve your issue(note that there is no need to invalidate the caches in this case):

```py
protocol = None
def provide_protocol(name):
    global protocol
    protocol = importlib.import_module(name)
```